# Return data in Json format with object name

Tags: c#, json, rest, ienumerable

Wrote a simple function for Web API 2 which returns the list of countries. It returns the valid Json format but without the array/object name. I have a bit of difficulty understand how this is achieved?

Here is my C# code:

```
[Route("Constants/CountryList")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetCountryList()
{
    IEnumerable<ISimpleListEntity> list = new CountryStore().SimpleSortedListByName();
    if (list == null || !list.Any())
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(list);
}
```

**ISimpleListEntity** interface code is here.

```
public interface ISimpleListEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This service returns the following Json output *(without the object/array name)*:

```
[  
   {  
      "Id":1,
      "Name":"[Select]"
   },
   {  
      "Id":4,
      "Name":"India"
   },
   {  
      "Id":3,
      "Name":"Singapore"
   },
   {  
      "Id":2,
      "Name":"United Arab Emirates"
   }
]
```

But, am struggling to achieve the following Json format *(WITH the object/array name called 'CountryList')*:

```
{  
   "CountryList":[  
      {  
         "Id":1,
         "Name":"[Select]"
      },
      {  
         "Id":4,
         "Name":"India"
      },
      {  
         "Id":3,
         "Name":"Singapore"
      },
      {  
         "Id":2,
         "Name":"United Arab Emirates"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could either create a specific class for this, as per the answer from Boas, or just use an anonymous type:

```
return Ok(new { CountryList = list });
```

Basically, you need an object with the appropriate property, one way or the other. If you want to deserialize this later and keep compile-time checking, it would be worth creating a class - but if you're either using dynamic typing or the consumer won't be the C# code anyway, then an anonymous type would be simpler.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava: I have no idea what you mean, I'm afraid. The OP is *producing* JSON, not consuming it.

Comment: That works like a charm! :) Thanks!

Do I need to worry about performance issue because we are creating a new object?

Comment: @CoderAbsolute: No - it's *one object*, and you're responding to a network request. You're already doing work to get the data... creating a single extra object is going to be utterly insignificant.

Answer (score 4):

thats because you are serializing a list

Yu could create a dto which has the property with the name you want and serialize this in stead of the list

```
public class MyDto
{
      public List<ISimpleListEntity> CountryList {get;Set;}
}
```

Comment: Just curious, how do I make use of this class in my service? Sorry for the stupid question, please understand am a beginner!

Comment: just create it var instance = new MyDto(){CountryList = list} Also have a look at @jon skeets reply he has posted a more elegant way

Comment: Infact, I have already implemented Jon Skeet's suggestion and it works for me. Then, I saw your proposal and started to wonder...

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use an anonymous type:

```
return Ok(new {
    CountryList = list
});
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33954618/1364007) to this question?

Comment: @WaiHaLee I see it's the same answer. When I answered it was'nt still present, see the answer time, anyway I received a downvote I think for that reason.

Comment: Ah - you're right. Jon beat you by 1 minute and 4 seconds - presumably while you were writing your answer he posted his.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the object name too then it'd be better to return a model that contains that list.

```
class Model
{
    IEnumerable<ISimpleListEntity> CountryList { get; set; };
}
```

Then in your controller

```
return Ok(new model() {CountryList= ... });
```